# Django Crispy Forms does not use specified template pack

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django project where I use `django-crispy-forms` to style my forms. (I use `{{ form|crispy }}` in my template file to insert the template) Works perfectly fine. Now I upgraded from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 and wanted to update my forms accordingly. I pip installed `crispy-bootstrap5` (package recommended on django-crispy-forms GitHub) and added `"crispy_bootstrap5"` to `INSTALLED_APPS` as well as added `CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"` and `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"` to my `settings.py` file. All according to crispy-bootstrap5's GitHub Page. But nothing changed. It still renders the same html as before. Maybe you can help me with getting that to work. Thank you.

Comment: Is the page cached perhaps?

Comment: No, caching is disabled in chrome's developer tools.